# How to fix the space around an svg icon in button?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, button

I am trying to make a button with a svg icon. But the svg icon is taking space like a margin all around it in the button.

I was making it with this svg code -

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="656.43794" height="512.49902" viewBox="-50.21898,227.25048,656.43794,512.49902">
  <g fill="#000000" fill-rule="nonzero" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="30" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-dasharray="" stroke-dashoffset="0" font-family="none" font-weight="none" font-size="none" text-anchor="none" style="mix-blend-mode: normal">
    <path d="M579.23627,312.09078l-371.74723,371.74722l-28.9288,28.9288c-15.97694,15.97694 -41.88067,15.97694 -57.8576,0l-28.9288,-28.9288l-115.01012,-115.01012c-15.97694,-15.97694 -15.97694,-41.88067 0,-57.8576c15.97694,-15.97694 41.88067,-15.97694 57.8576,0l115.01012,115.01012l371.74721,-371.74721c15.97694,-15.97694 41.88067,-15.97694 57.8576,0c15.97694,15.97694 15.97694,41.88066 0.00001,57.85759z" id="Path 1" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

This is my js code with which I am manipulating my button -

```
async function submitClicked() {

 local1 = document.getElementById("submitButton");

 if (document.getElementById("textInput").value.trim() !="") {

  document.getElementById("textInput").style.borderBottom = "3px solid green";

  document.getElementById("textInput").disabled = true;

  local1.style.width = '55%';

  await sleep(0.25);

  local1.innerHTML = `Redirecting <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" id="checkmark" width="656.43794" height="512.49902" viewBox="-50.21898,227.25048,656.43794,512.49902"><g fill="#000000" fill-rule="nonzero" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="30" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-dasharray="" stroke-dashoffset="0" font-family="none" font-weight="none" font-size="none" text-anchor="none" style="mix-blend-mode: normal"><path d="M579.23627,312.09078l-371.74723,371.74722l-28.9288,28.9288c-15.97694,15.97694 -41.88067,15.97694 -57.8576,0l-28.9288,-28.9288l-115.01012,-115.01012c-15.97694,-15.97694 -15.97694,-41.88067 0,-57.8576c15.97694,-15.97694 41.88067,-15.97694 57.8576,0l115.01012,115.01012l371.74721,-371.74721c15.97694,-15.97694 41.88067,-15.97694 57.8576,0c15.97694,15.97694 15.97694,41.88066 0.00001,57.85759z" id="Path 1"/></g></svg>`

  local1.disabled = true;

 } else {

  document.getElementById("textInput").style.borderBottom = "3px solid red";

  local1.style.background = 'red';

  local1.style.width = "50%";

  local1.innerHTML = `Submit <i class="fa-solid fa-xmark"></i>`

 }

}
```

The submitClicked function is triggered when the button is clicked and the text gets manipulated.

My CSS:

```
#submitButton {

 display: flex;

 justify-content: space-evenly;

 align-items: center;

 margin-top: 2vh;

 color: black;

 fill: black !important;

 background: var(--theme);

 border-radius: 1rem;

 font-family: var(--font1);

 transition: background ease 0.5s, color ease 0.5s, border-radius ease 0.5s, width ease 0.5s, fill ease 0.5s;

 height: 10%;

 width: 40%;

 border: none;

 text-align: center;

 font-size: 3vw;

 padding: 1rem;

}

#submitButton:hover {

 cursor: pointer;

}

#checkmark {

 width: 50%;

 height: 50%;

 margin: 0;

 padding: 0;

}
```

What I expect is to remove the extra margin around the icon. I tried doing `margin: 0` and `padding: 0` too but it didn't work well.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the height and width from the SVG.

```css
svg {
  height: 75vh;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="-50.21898,227.25048,656.43794,512.49902"><g fill="#000000" fill-rule="nonzero" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="30" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-dasharray="" stroke-dashoffset="0" font-family="none" font-weight="none" font-size="none" text-anchor="none" style="mix-blend-mode: normal"><path d="M579.23627,312.09078l-371.74723,371.74722l-28.9288,28.9288c-15.97694,15.97694 -41.88067,15.97694 -57.8576,0l-28.9288,-28.9288l-115.01012,-115.01012c-15.97694,-15.97694 -15.97694,-41.88067 0,-57.8576c15.97694,-15.97694 41.88067,-15.97694 57.8576,0l115.01012,115.01012l371.74721,-371.74721c15.97694,-15.97694 41.88067,-15.97694 57.8576,0c15.97694,15.97694 15.97694,41.88066 0.00001,57.85759z" id="Path 1"/></g></svg>
```